# RDF or OWL based Rapid Application Development Framework?

Tags: forms, rdf, owl, ontology, scaffolding

I am looking for an easy-to-implement solution for form-based ontology editing and I wonder if there are any **active projects** and which of them is the right path to follow.

I need to create instances of an ontology (lets call it ontology A) using forms (either web or desktop) and store them in a triple store (e.g. Virtuoso). I would like to hide as much details as possible regarding the ontological relationships between the entities defined in ontology A and provide a plain simple user interface for CRUD (Create-Retrieve-Update-Delete) operations based on the entity schema defined in ontology A.

For example, I have found two possible solutions in the protege ecosystem:

1. [PropertyFormPortlet](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/PropertyFormPortlet) It is not a live feature in the current webprotege version.
2. [facsimile project](https://github.com/protegeproject/facsimile)
   As described in the respective [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5540339/) this is a solution that has been implemented for a specific context. Therefore, adapting it to another domain would not be as straightforward as I would like.

I wonder, is there another solution (even out of the protege ecosystem) that could facilitate such a form-based ontology editing. Could somebody provide some guidance?

Comment: I am currently evaluating the approach described in http://inova8.com/bg_inova8.com/really-rapid-rdf-graph-application-development/ but I will have to do some pilot testing before announcing it as a possible solution

Comment: RDFAuthor, SemanticForms, OntoWiki, RDFforms, etc. ? By the way asking for tools is not really the place for StackOverflow. The question will be closed soon I guess

Comment: @AKSW: Thank you very much for your guidance. I will evaluate the provided tools and answer the question accordingly. I agree that the question could be considered "opinion based" but I could not think of a more suitable forum to post on.

Comment: @AKSW: Could you provide some links regarding SemanticForms and RDFforms? I cannot find useful information about them.

Comment: @AKSW: Could you please check the issue https://github.com/AKSW/OntoWiki/issues/439? I have also posted a relevant question on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305643/ontowiki-hangs-while-trying-to-add-property) and sent an email in the OntoWiki user list

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone lands in this question, I write down my conclusions. Practically, none of which I tried worked, but still I found out some interesting things.

[OpenLink Structured Data Editor](http://osde.openlinksw.com/):
OSDE is a browser plugin which aims at populating RDF graphs in the form of files, based on Linked Vocabularies. In my case it didn't work as my locally hosted ontology cannot play the role of a "Linked Vocabulary". However, OpenLink team said they will work on it.

[OData2SPARQL](http://inova8.com/bg_inova8.com/really-rapid-rdf-graph-application-development/):
In our test, the WebIDE did not manage to create the forms out of the box as suggested by the respective video tutorial. However, we managed to use OpenUI library as a client of the OData services automatically created by OData2SPARQL, providing a web service interface for our ontology.

[Ontowiki](http://docs.ontowiki.net/):
In our test environment, OntoWiki partially worked. We could save data but there were some bugs when trying to add properties etc. OntoWiki developers said that they plan to refactor in order to actively support it in newer hosting settings, but this is not the case right now.